# The same scala Task code works in sandbox but doesn't work in intelliJ

Tags: scala, monix

Just try some simple Task examples. The following code works fine

```scala
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.CancelableFuture
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

import scala.util.Success

val task = Task { 1 + 1 }
val cancellable = task.runAsync {
  case Right(result) => println(s"result is $result")
  case Left(err) => System.out.println(s"ERROR: ${err.getMessage}")
}
```

but using runToFuture works only in sandbox, not when i run it in intelliJ (of course in intelliJ i run it inside object)

```
val task = Task { 1 + 1 }

val future: CancelableFuture[Int] = task.runToFuture
future.onComplete {
  case Success(res) => println(s"result is: $res")
}
```

in intelliJ no printing 2, just

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe"
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

What can be cause, i didn't expect stuck so early. Thanks in advance

Comment: The best would be to use `TaskApp` instead of calling any of the unsafe methods.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thanks, i just leartn and try simple things now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When run as a stand-alone program, the program exits before the task completes, so you don't get any output. You need to wait for the task to complete.

```
Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: ok, i got, it works, but  if i use delay it does not work even with Await. Do you know why? `val task = Task { 1 + 1 }.delayExecution(1.second)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Monix so I'm not sure why that is.